# Choosing File Format of /home between NTFS and Ext4, Understanding Trade Offs in Performance vs Data sharing with WinXP in Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, ext4, home, ntfs

- I have Win Xp on first Primary Partition.
- I am leaving another 2 primaries for a future possible Win install.
- I am planning my Logical partitions to install a Linux Mint.
- I read that a separate /home gives re-usability across future Linus'es.
- I thought it might be clever to keep /home as NTFS, to smoothly share data across Win and Linux too.
- I am anxious though as most of the forums declare NTFS inferior to ext4.
- But some forums said that performance of file system is not as much driven by its structure, but mainly by the kernel driver and algorithms for read and write.

Questions

- If Linux has good algorithms [as implemented with ext4], wont it perform same on NTFS too?
- May be the inferiority of NTFS is only with windows, But same NTFS performs equally well on ext4?
- If not, Is the peformance low enough to stay away from NTFS, and think of other ways to share data across Win and Linux?
- Does ways exist to read ext4 from WinXp or 7?
- Any other recommendations from practical experiences are welcome.

Comment: Specs: Laptop HP6530S,   Core2duo 1.8MHz, Ram 1GB+2GB, No SSD

Comment: Usage: Software Programming, Movies, Music, Office tools, etc.

Comment: The post seems broad, but questions are attempted to be straight forward. Kindly allow

Comment: @Wouter Verhelst has succinctly covered all my questions along with side notes from his experience.   Precisely my need.  Proves my question was answerable in one para.      I have further requested him some info regarding his side notes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux implementation of NTFS is not very good. There is some write support, but it is slow. This is due to the fact that the best NTFS for Linux implementation, `NTFS-3G`, is a FUSE filesystem, where every filesystem call gets redirected to a userspace program, a strategy which carries with it a sever performance penalty.

Apart from that, the NTFS filesystem is written to implement Windows security principles, rather than Linux ones. As a result, mapping Linux usernames and groups to Windows filesystem security properties is going to be complicated at best. You don't want to have that issue on a home directory.

In all, `NTFS-3G` is useful as a way to share data between Windows and Linux, but beyond that I wouldn't use it.

If you want to share your Linux home directory with a Windows operating system, rather than trying to use NTFS as your home directory's file system, it's better to install something like [ext2fsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) on your Windows machine, which supports reading the `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4` file systems from Windows. Combined with `NTFS-3G`, this should allow you to easily share data between Windows and Linux without ever having to reboot to get at data from your other operating system.

On a side note, if you're still on Windows XP, you should stop using it and upgrade *now*. Windows XP has not been receiving security updates in [over a year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#End_of_support), which means your XP machine is probably part of a botnet that is spamming me (and everyone else in the world) now. Additionally, Windows XP does not support several SSL algorithms that are going to be very much required going forward (e.g., the SHA2 set of hashing algorithms) if you want to still be able to use SSL-enabled websites.

Comment: Decided: EXT4 on /Home, ext2fsd on win.
XP Thoughts:
Agreed XP is outdated, recently i had to borrow a Win7 pc to attend a WebEx chat, as they stopped XP support this year.
That nudged me to put a Win7 on my 30 GB 2nd primary.
But isn't Win7 heavy for my specs, as XP itself has gone slow.
Also felt that Linux [Mint 17.2] might eliminate need to fall back on Win7 at all.
But practically, i feel there will Always be situations when Windows is handy or required.

So, Shall i just focus on Linux as of now, and keep falling back on existing Xp for those seldom needs?
Or still put up with a Win7 ?